# Is the Easter island question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Starting a discussion here to avoid a large number of comments.

This question:

[How did people travel to remote islands like Easter Island?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/61/how-did-people-find-remote-islands-like-easter-island)

Has three close votes and bunch of comments discussing why it is or isn't off topic.

Should this type of question, which isn't about a particular event but discussing how a people operated be on topic?

Comment: Note I have edited the questions title (pending)

Comment: let's vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 14):

I personally think this should be on topic. There is already an answer that exists for this out there so it can be answered factually.

How people traveled between countries and how certain countries were colonised is an important part of history. So I vote to keep it open.

I suggest maybe the question lacks a bit of meat, but it is still a reasonable question IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

I also think that it is on topic, now. Before it sounded like, "How did people discover islands back then".

Answer (score 5):

I think it's on-topic, since it's a question about how people back in the past did things. It's not subjective, since it can be answered objectively, with facts.

Answer (score 5):

I am new to history.SE, but from my experience on other SE sites this looks like an on-topic question. The question has a definitive answer, both for the specific case of Easter Island and for Polynesian islands in general. It is a history question because it pertains to the use of technology and methods that are no longer in use today.

I am biased, though, as the answer touches upon my *real* hobby: astronomy!